# Why is React not displaying any data?

Tags: django, reactjs

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
```

I would like to display this on the page:

```
class ProjectDeatil extends Component {

constructor(props) {
   super(props);

   this.state = { user: { name: '' } };
}
```

.

```
componentDidMount() {

const { match: { params } } = this.props;

axios.get(`http://localhost:8000/api/project/${params.pk}`)
  .then(({ data: user }) => {
    console.log( user);

    this.setState({"User:": user });
  });
 }
```

I added her const

```
 render() {
     const{ user } = this.state;
return (
```

Then I tried displaying it again and it still didn't work

```
 <div className="col-md-4 text-white   animated fadeInUp delay-2s if " >
 <h1>{user.title}</h1>
 <h1> Hello Dear</h1>
 </div>
```

I also tried using django rest api and that also didn't work.

```
    </div>




  );
  }  
}
 export default ProjectDeatil
```

Comment: Please format your code properly (not putting code in separate containers and indenting).  This will help others understand what you are doing.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to _StackOverflow!_ I think you may benefit from a [really good tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on asking questions here. Consider editing your question and using the formatting toolbar to make `code` more readable. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You have to fix this line:

```
this.setState({"User:": user });
```

to

```
this.setState({"user": user });
```